# There is a function in Matlab to create a matrix, where each element is the same function of matrix indexes?

Tags: matlab

For example, a matrix where each value at row r and column c is

```
a=[r^2+c^2]
```

like `a=[1, 4; 4; 18]`

or

```
A=[F(r,c)]

A=[F(1,1) F(1,2) F(1,3);
   F(2,1) F(2,2) F(2,3);
   F(3,1) F(3,2) F(3,3)]
```

or

```
A(r,c)=F(r,c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mehtod  1

You can do it manually. First, create two matrices for rows and columns indices (suppose the matrix is `n x m`):

```
R = repmat((1:n).',[1, m]); 
C = repmat((1:m),[n, 1]);
```

Then, write the function base on these two:

```
result = R.^2 + C.^2; % F(x,y) = x^2 + y^2
```

Or define the function inline and apply it on those two:

```
F = @(x,y)(x.^2 + y.^2);
result = F(R,C);
```

### Mehtod  2

By @Cris Luengo, you can do it the first part by the `meshgird` function as well. Hence, we can generate `R` and `C` like the following:

```
[C,R] = meshgrid(1:n, 1:m)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's one of those solutions that makes me slap the forehead, and say "off course". Elegant.